# Newbie: for i in range not incrementing

Tags: python

I am trying to do an assignment for class and making it much harder than needed, but I am doing that to learn.

Can anyone see the issue with my code?

I did some simple searches and tried a few fixes, but I must be missing something basic.

Also, I cannot seem to add up all the items in my list 'new'.  After looking around I still cannot figure this out.  As the subject says, I am new to this so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
# define variables
new = []
items = float()
tax = float()
final = float()
subtotal = float()

# welcome and set rules of entering numbers
print("Welcome! Sales tax is 7%. Enter your five items, one (1) at a time.")

# gathering input for items
for _ in range(5):
    _ += 1
    # define condition to continue gathering input
    test = True
    while test:  # test1 will verify integer or float entered for item1
        items = input("Enter the price of item without the $: ")
        try:
            val = float(items)
            print("Input amount is :", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(val))
            test1 = False
        except ValueError:
            try:
                val = float(items)
                print("Input amount is :", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(val))
                test = False
            except ValueError:
                print("That is not a number")
    new.append(items)


# define calculations
subtotal = sum(new)
tax = subtotal * .07
final = subtotal + tax

# tax & subtotal
print("Subtotal: ", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(subtotal))
print("Tax: ", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(tax))
print("Tare: ", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(final))
```

Comment: The way `for` loops work in python, the 'control variable' (`_` in this case) gets reset every iteration of the loop, to the next element of the iterable you gave after `in`. If you want to replicate the behavior of a 'classical' for loop, rather than a for-each loop that python has, then I recommend using a `while` loop instead.

Comment: btw your variable `test1` is unused, might be causing some unexpected behaviour in your code (?)

Comment: As an aside, do *not* use `_` as a variable like that, this is conventionally used for "throwaway" variables to signal "ignore this variable". But you are *actually using it*, e.g. `_ += 1` so that is very confusing

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't get the final calculations at end is the loops do not actually terminate. Also your list is populated with strings by `new.append(items)`. You would want to `new.append(val)` so it will add the values.

Here is a version which approaches this with @Green Cloak Guy 's suggestion of a while loop.  I made this so it will add any number of values, with a definite "END" condition, in which the user types 'end' to quit and get a total.  `items.upper()` makes any letters uppercase, so you can compare to "END", and still catch "end", "End" or "eNd".

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# define variables
# you do not have to declare variables in python, but we do have to 
# state that new is an empty list for new.append() to work later
new = []

# welcome and set rules of entering numbers
print("Welcome! Sales tax is 7%. Enter your five items, one (1) at a time.")
print('Type "end" to stop and total items')

# gathering input for items
while True:
    items = input("Enter the price of item without the $: ")
    if items.upper() == 'END':
        break
    try:
        val = float(items)
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a valid number.  Try again, or 'end' to stop")
    new.append(val)

# define calculations
subtotal = sum(new)
tax = subtotal * .07
final = subtotal + tax

# tax & subtotal
print("Subtotal: ", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(subtotal))
print("Tax: ", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(tax))
print("Tare: ", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(final))
```

Comment: I rewrote based on feedback

Answer (score 0):

So the problem turns out to be your `while` loop.

In disguise your `while` loop is `while True:` and stays like that forever until, the user inputs some text or string which branches to the `except`, but then again does it?
I'm pretty sure one `except` will work as your code is doing the `except` twice even though it branches

```py
try:
    val = float(items)
    print("Input amount is :", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(val))
    test1 = False
except ValueError:
    try:
        val = float(items)
        print("Input amount is :", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(val))
        test = False
```

you probably don't need the 2nd try statement as a whole and replace it with `print("That is not a number")` and `test = False`

You control (`_`) is not being use inside anywhere in your code, so I would just remove `_ += 1`

My understanding

Now what I think you want to do is to take 5 items from the user and if the user's input is isn't a proper float, it asks it again until the user has 5 inputs correct.

Your `for` loop can be replaced with this:

First make sure you have a counter variable like `v` or `c` and assign it to `0`.

We want to get input from the user `while` the counter variable is less that 5 which is range of `0,1,2,3,4` (5 times).

If the user input is correct, you can increment the counter by 1, but when it isn't you don't do anything and we `continue`

In `try` statements the first line can be whatever you want to test, in this case `float(input("............."))` and below those lines you can add things you want to do if the input is correct and no errors are thrown out, in our case it will be to increment the counter by one (`v += 1`) and append it to `new`. Now the `except` is what we want to do if the user input isn't correct and throws out a `ValueError` which in our case would be to `continue`. When an error is thrown, it directly jumps to the `except` and doesn't execute the next line.

So here's the final loop for taking user input:

```py
v = 0

while v < 5:
    items = input("...........")
    try:
        float(items)
        v += 1
        new.append(items)
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

and the rest of the code can be the same!

```py
#defining variables
v = 0
new = []
items = float()
tax = float()
final = float()
subtotal = float()

#gathering input from items
while v < 5:
    items = input("Enter the price of item without the $: ")
    try:
        float(items)
        v += 1
        print("Input amount is :", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(float(items)))
        new.append(float(items))
    except ValueError:
        continue


# define calculations
subtotal = sum(new)
tax = subtotal * .07
final = subtotal + tax

# tax & subtotal
print("Subtotal: ", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(subtotal))
print("Tax: ", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(tax))
print("Tare: ", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(final))
```

That's all! Hope you understood why...

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up the output and used the feedback to make it work better.  Now if people have suggestions on simplifying the code that would be great as well.  I want to make sure I am writing things in a pythonic way and also efficient from a memory usage and code space perspective.

Thanks to everyone for all the help so far!

```
# define variables
new = []
items = float()
subtotal = float()
tax = float()
final = float()
    
# welcome and set rules of entering numbers
print("Welcome! Sales tax is 7%. Enter your five items, one (1) at a time.")

# gathering input for items
for _ in range(5):
    # define condition to continue gathering input
    test = True
    while test:  # test1 will verify integer or float entered for item1
        items = input("\nEnter the price of item without the $: ")
        try:
            val = float(items)
            print("Input amount is :", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(val))
            test = False
        except ValueError:
            try:
                val = float(items)
                print("Input amount is :", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(val))
                test = False
            except ValueError:
                print("That is not a number")
    # append items to the list defined as new
    new.append(items)
    # define calculations
    subtotal += float(items)
    tax = subtotal * .07
    print("Cost Subtotal: ", "$" + "{0:.2f}".format(subtotal), " & Tax Subtotal: ", "$" + "{0:.2f}".format(tax))
    _ += 1
    
# define calculations
final = subtotal + tax

# items tax & subtotal
print("\n Final list of item cost:")
new_list = [float(item) for item in new] # fixed this too
for i in new_list:
    print("- $"+"{0:.2f}".format(i))
print("\n Final Pretax Total: ", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(subtotal))
print(" Final Tax: ", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(tax))
print("\n Tare: ", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(final))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

```
new = []
items = float()
tax = float()
final = float()
subtotal = float()

# welcome and set rules of entering numbers
print("Welcome! Sales tax is 7%. Enter your five items, one (1) at a time.")

try:
    new = list(map(lambda x: float(x), list(map(input, range(5)))))
except:
    print("Some values are not a number")

# define calculations
subtotal = sum(new)
tax = subtotal * .07
final = subtotal + tax

# tax & subtotal
print("Subtotal: ", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(subtotal))
print("Tax: ", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(tax))
print("Tare: ", "$"+"{0:.2f}".format(final))
```